# How to pass wildcards in command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, php

So this works:

```
foo -a -b -c "path/file.ext"
```

And this too if I want to pass all files from directory:

```
foo -a -b -c path/*
```

But if I add the quotes

```
foo -a -b -c "path/*"
```

It doesn't work anymore: it says "no such file..."

And I think I need to add the quotes in order to escape arguments (I'm using PHP and `escapeshellarg`).

Comment: What exactly expects that foo?

Comment: A list of file paths and it also supports wildcards

Comment: it seems it does not support wildcards, as evidenced by the 'no such file' error

Comment: Please explain exactly what `foo` is, the details will depend on it.

Comment: Why do you think you need `escapeshellarg`?  This sounds like more of a PHP question than a UNIX/Linux question.

Comment: it's a application called "jhead". I thought all apps are the same, and it doesn't matter the format of the arguments

Comment: All apps are not the same. Please show us the exact command you are running, explain if this is done on the command line or through a webserver and why you don't simply use `foo -a -b -c path/*` which seems to work.

Comment: because in the php manual for exec() function it says i should use escapeshellarg(): When allowing user-supplied data to be passed to this function, use escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() to ensure that users cannot trick the system into executing arbitrary commands.

Comment: Don't use `foo`. Show us which command you're actually using, if you want an accurate answer. Try to reproduce your problem from the command line. If it only happens when you call it from PHP, your question would be better suited for StackOverflow than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [escapeshellarg docs say it turns it into](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):
"a single safe argument"

But you want it to be interpreted as multiple arguments.

Try doing the expansion using [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) first.